# Parse - Check if user exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a problem with Parse.com.

I wanna check, if a user already exist. I do this with following code:

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

if ([query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:textField.text]) {
    NSLog(@"User exist");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"User don`t exist");
}
```

But every time I check, it will say: User exist. But that isn`t impossible.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You aren't actually running the query, you're configuring the query in an 'if' statement...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should have something more like:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:textField.text];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (object != nil) {
        NSLog(@"User exist");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"User don`t exist");
    }
}];
```